# Send keystrokes from vbscript to a CMD window

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, sendkeys

I run a batch file as part of Windows XP startup which executes continuously until Windows closes. It calls a VBScript file, which executes `SendKeys "+{ESC}"` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>). This gets picked up by 4t Tray Minimiser to send the CMD window to the system tray. Most times it works, but occasionally the CMD window stays visible.

Upon searching, various posts seem to suggest the .VBS file is losing focus or it's a timing problem. Some suggest `AppActivate` but I can't work out how to achieve what I want. Even the examples given for `AppActivate` seem like a lot of work.

Comment: Use `AppActivate`. Use `wscript.sleep`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)? It's actually rather straightforward. You call `AppActivate` with the title (or part of the title) of the window you want to bring to the foreground, then run `SendKeys` to send keystrokes to the foreground window.

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

sh.AppActivate "window title"
sh.SendKeys "+{Esc}"
```